# Gravitational potential energy for more than two object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, vectors

When an object of mass $m_1$ is brought from infinity to an object of mass $m_2$ the gravitational potential energy of the system is
$-\frac{Gm_1m_2}{d}$.  Now if an object of mass $m_3$ is brought from infinity to this system, what will be the gravitational potential energy of the whole system? Is there any vector calculation?

Answer (score 3):

For an arbitrary number of particles, just sum that expression, $-Gm_im_j/|\vec r_i-\vec r_j|$, over all pairs $i$, $j$ of particles. This is easy to see if you imagine bringing each particle successively into the potential of the particles already present, since the potentials of individual particles just add together.

Comment: The gravitational force is working here. For two objects it is parallel to displacement. But for a third object, the gravitational force may not be parallel to the displacement toward the previous two objects.
So why we don't calculate the vector components of gravitational force?

Comment: You can, but the problem is simplified because the force is the gradient of a potential, $F/m=-\nabla\phi$. This implies that the work integral from one point (e.g. infinity) to another is just the difference in the potential at the two points (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem). The potential due to a point mass $m$ is $-Gm/r$ at distance $r$, and for multiple masses the potentials add together.